# magento multistore with global accounts but with different address per website

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, customer-account, shipping-address

I have a magento 1.9.2.4 with multistore (3 websites), and it has configured global accounts.

I need to filter the customer addresses by website.

For example, let's say the countries are France, Germany and UK.

If a customer with a french shipping address logs in the german website, I need that the french address is not available in the german website (or the Uk website).

If a customer with a german shipping address logs in the UK website, it shouldn't have available the german address in the UK website (or french).

But I have no clue where I should begin with this....

**EDIT:**
In *system > configuration > SALES > Shipping Methods > Ship to Applicable Countries* I have set `Specific Countries` option and selected a different country by website.

Now, customers can't ship to a different country, but I need to not list at all the addresses from another countries and the other countries addresses are still there.

**EDIT 2:**
I'm still searching, and I've tracked this code in app/design/frontend/rwd/myproject/template/opc/onepage/billing.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
    <li class="wide">
        <label for="billing-address-select" class="notice"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and getAddressesHtmlSelect leads me to:

```
public function getAddressesHtmlSelect($type)
{
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses() as $address) {
            $options[] = array(
                'value' => $address->getId(),
                'label' => $address->format('oneline')
            );
        }

        $addressId = $this->getAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();
        if (empty($addressId)) {
            if ($type=='billing') {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
            } else {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            }
            if ($address) {
                $addressId = $address->getId();
            }
        }

        $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'_address_id')
            ->setId($type.'-address-select')
            ->setClass('address-select')
            ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
            ->setValue($addressId)
            ->setOptions($options);

        $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));

        return $select->getHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a solution, I copy it here because it maybe helps somebody in the future:

I had to override app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php with app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php, and there I changed the function getAddressesHtmlSelect() with this code:

```
public function getAddressesHtmlSelect($type)
{
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $options = array();
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $all_addresses = $this->getCustomer()->getAddresses();

        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/sallowspecific', $store_id)) {
            $allowed_countries = explode( ',', Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/specificcountry', $store_id) );
            foreach ($all_addresses as $address) {

                if (in_array($address->getCountryId(), $allowed_countries)) {
                    $options[] = array(
                        'value' => $address->getId(),
                        'label' => $address->format('oneline')
                    );
                }

            }
        } else {
            foreach ($all_addresses as $address) {
                $options[] = array(
                    'value' => $address->getId(),
                    'label' => $address->format('oneline')
                );
            }
        }

        if (!empty($options)) {

            $addressId = $this->getAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();
            if (empty($addressId)) {
                if ($type=='billing') {
                    $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
                } else {
                    $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
                }
                if ($address) {
                    $addressId = $address->getId();
                }
            }

            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
                ->setName($type.'_address_id')
                ->setId($type.'-address-select')
                ->setClass('address-select')
                ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
                ->setValue($addressId)
                ->setOptions($options);

            $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));

            return $select->getHtml();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return '';
}
```

next stop is to change the app/design/frontend/rwd/myproject/template/opc/onepage/billing.phtml and app/design/frontend/rwd/myproject/template/opc/onepage/shipping.phtml with following code:

```
<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
   <li class="wide">
       <label for="shipping-address-select" class="notice"><?php echo $this->__('Select a shipping address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
           <?php $select_address = $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('shipping'); ?>  // this is for shipping.phtml, remember to change the argument 'shipping' for 'billing' in the billing.phtml
            <?php echo $select_address ?>
       </div>
   </li>
<?php endif ?>
<li id="shipping-new-address-form"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses() && $select_address ): ?> style="display:none;"<?php endif ?>>
```

And in the end there is only rest to comment the values of the billing/shipping form inputs to not being autocompleted with the default address.